# Sort (Array array, System.Collections.IComparer? comparer) - parameter or implementation?

Tags: c#

The Methode Array.Sort() has the following signature

```
public static void Sort (Array array, System.Collections.IComparer? comparer);
```

It looks like you need to pass an IComparer reference. But what is really needed is that array needs to implements IComparable, isn't it?

I see this syntax the first time. Is this common? How can I differentiate between a real parameter? Is there somewhere more information about this topic (in general)?

**Important/Edit:** ATM I'm reading a C# book and it says about Sort.Array (translated from German to English):

> To the first parameter we pass the array to be sorted, in our case
> arr. The second parameter is of type IComparer interface. Of course,
> you can't pass an instance of type IComparer to the method call,
> because interfaces are not instantiable. This is not how the type
> specification of the second parameter should be understood. Instead,
> the second parameter simply requires that the fist argument passed to
> it be an object that implements the interface IComparer - whether the
> object is of type DemoClass, Circle,

Basically he says that the second parameter is kind of a description for the first parameter. Is he correct or maybe that's just wrong and the source for my confusion?

https://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/visual_csharp_2012/1997_04_008.html

I just implemented the following snippet. So this could be a way how to pass the second parameter, right?

```
    Array.Sort(shapes, (a, b) => {
        if (a.GetArea() < b.GetArea()) return -1;
        else if (a.GetArea() > b.GetArea()) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
```

Comment: This specific overload is the one you use if you *don't* want to use array's `IComparable` implementation. There are [17 overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-6.0#overloads).

Comment: How can I call this specific overload? It works fine with Array.Sort(myArray). Where myArray is an array of custom types that implement IComparable. I'm just wondering: how can I pass the second parameter for the >> Sort (Array array, System.Collections.IComparer? comparer); << ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not pass the comparer it will use the default comparer implementation for the Array items. But if you have a special comparer then you can pass your own custom Comparer to sort the elements.

Suppose you have a Class of Students (Array of Students), and your default Student comparer can be based on total marks. However, a maths teacher may want to sort the Students based on marks for the Maths only, in that case maths teacher can write his custom `MathsRankComparer` and pass it to the Sort method so that he will get the Students ordered by marks in Maths.

Similarly, English or Science teacher can pass the respective comparers to get their required ranking/ordering/sorting.

Hope this helps in understanding use of that overload.

Update: some examples to understand details.

```
    public class Student: IComparable<Student>
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float TotalMarks { get; set; }
        public float ScienceMarks { get; set; }
        public float MathsMarks { get; set; }
        public float EnglishMarks { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Student other)
        {
            if (this.TotalMarks == other.TotalMarks)
                return 0;
            if (this.TotalMarks < other.TotalMarks)
                return -1;

            return 1;
        }
    }

    public class MathsMarksBasedComparer : System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<Student>
    {
        public int Compare(Student a, Student b)
        {
            if (a.MathsMarks == b.MathsMarks)
                return 0;
            if (a.MathsMarks < b.MathsMarks)
                return -1;

            return 1;
        }
    }

    public class EnglishMarksBasedComparer : System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<Student>
    {
        public int Compare(Student a, Student b)
        {
            if (a.EnglishMarks == b.EnglishMarks)
                return 0;
            if (a.EnglishMarks < b.EnglishMarks)
                return -1;

            return 1;
        }
    }
```

And finally, you can use them like this.

```
        Student[] arr = new Student[100]; // Ignore this, you can use other styles of declaration
        Array.Sort(arr, new EnglishMarksBasedComparer());
        Array.Sort(arr, new MathsMarksBasedComparer());
        Array.Sort(arr);
```

Comment: I just updated the description with a translation from a book. Could you please take 2min and give me some feedback? Maybe the content of the book is wrong and the source of my confusion...

Comment: @TheAnonymousModeIT You're right, that book explanation confused you. method parameters never describe the other parameter, I mean the 2nd parameter IComparer is not describing the arr to implement IComparer for it.  My suggestion is to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/use-icomparable-icomparer for uptodate and trusted information. Updated my answer to give some more info that you might find useful.

Comment: Not quite true: there is also type inference for generic parameters, so one parameter could affect the other

Answer (score 1):

> Basically he says that the second parameter is kind of a description for the first parameter. Is he correct or maybe that's just wrong and the source for my confusion?

It's not wrong it's just worded a bit confusingly.
The `IComparer` is a nullable type (defined by the questionmark at the end of `IComparer`). This states that the `IComparer` is optional/does not have to be passed. However as Mahesh Bongani already meantioned in his reply - internaly if you do not provide a comparer it takes the defualt comparer of the object.

So for this particular funtion if you would pass a Array with objects that do not implement a comparable the function wouldn't be able to sort the elements properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen IComparer a few times and am unsure what implements it as standard - as far as lists, arrays and things go. I do know that numbers implement it and I think string does too.
You can though custom implement this inferface. If memory serves me correctly, it provides just one method (interface so you have to write logic yourself) that returns an int. -1 (<0) is lower ranked, +1(>0) is higher ranked, 0 is the same.